# Eclipse cannot import import com.google.maps.* (For java Fx programme)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am working on a Java fx application and I need to import some libraries from com.google.maps.
I imported these libraries :

```
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.PlaceDetailsRequest;
import com.google.maps.PlacesApi;
import com.google.maps.QueryAutocompleteRequest;
import com.google.maps.errors.ApiException;
import com.google.maps.model.AddressComponent;
import com.google.maps.model.AddressComponentType;
import com.google.maps.model.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.maps.model.PlaceDetails;
```

Comment: What are you doing to include the API jars. Just expecting the packages/classes to get imported does not work.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in the default package? If yes, have you added the `requires` statement for the module?

Comment: You need to add the jar(s) containing those classes and possibly additional jars they depend on. Depending on the project type there are different ways to go about this. E.g. editing the pom.xml for maven projects or using the project properties to add additional jars to the classpath (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars)...

Answer (score 0):

The java `import` statement is a little bit misnamed, it really means `alias`. `import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;` really just means: Any time you find the type `GeoApiContext` anywhere in this source file, assume I meant to write `com.google.maps.GeoApiContext`.

Crucially, it does not 'invoke' any code in that class whatsoever, nor does it find or download any dependencies from the internet for you.

You will need to find the jar(s) that provide these classes and put them on the classpath of this project.

It can be as simple as downloading the relevant jar (perhaps com.google.maps-google-maps-services.jar?), put it in a lib dir someplace inside this project, finding that in the package explorer, right clicking it, and selecting 'add to classpath'.

Or, more likely, you want to use gradle or maven to take care of this for you: These tools turn simply mentioning the dependency in a list of libraries you require into automatically finding that on the internet, downloading it, configuring your IDE so that it knows where it is, and using that dependency during build and run steps.